# Как связать ползунок с фильтрацией по цене товаров в jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gui, jquery-ui

Есть **slider range**, натянутый плагином **jquery UI** (https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range ). Сам ползунок работает отлично, но нужно его связать с товарами, чтобы при редактировании цены выводились товары подходящие по цене.

Answer (score 0):

Там есть событие изменения, которое нужно "слушать":

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

А потом как реализовывать показ нужных товаров уже зависит от тебя и от текущей реализации , я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Пробегать по DOM элементам с товарами и прятать те, которые не подходят.
2. Кидать запрос ajax с параметром слайдера и ререндерить товары.